# 'Manager' object has no attribute 'normalize_email'

Tags: python, django

I have a fairly simple model with a many-to-many relationship:

```py
class Person(AbstractUser):
...
    topics = models.ManyToManyField("web.Topic", through="Interests", blank=True)
...

    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return "{last}, {first} ({id})".format(
            last=self.last_name, first=self.first_name, id=self.id
        )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ("last_name", "first_name")
```

Based on that model, I have a form defined by:

```py
class TopicForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ("topics",)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TopicForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields["topics"].widget = SelectMultiple(attrs={"size": 20})
        self.fields["topics"].queryset = Topic.objects.order_by(Lower("name")).all()
        self.fields[
            "topics"
        ].help_text = "Don't forget to hold the CTRL key (or cmd on a Mac) to select multiple topics"
```

Finally, the view looks like:

```
def update_my_profile(request):
    topics_form = TopicForm(request.POST or None, instance=request.user)

    if request.method == "POST":
      if topics_form.is_valid():
                topics_form.save()
    
    context = {
        "topics_form": topics_form,
    }
    return render(request, "web/profile.html", context)
```

for a reason I really don't get, the django framework is failing on `if topics_form.is_valid():` I get the following error message:

> 'Manager' object has no attribute 'normalize_email'

Surprinsingly, the failing code is within the django framework (django/contrib/auth/models.py in clean at line 365):

```
    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        self.email = self.__class__.objects.normalize_email(self.email)
```

Even more surprisingly, if I put a breakpoint (in VSCode) at the line `if topics_form.is_valid():` and run the command manually in the debug console, it does not fail...

what did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
objects = models.Manager()
```

from `Person` model, so it can use the proper Manager that is specified in `AbstractUser` class.