# Custom authentication middleware not working when objects is not overridden in model definition

Tags: django, django-models

Following the question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65180346/manager-object-has-no-attribute-normalize-email)

I have a custom authentication middleware that does not work anymore if I do not override the `objects`.

The models.py looks like this:

```py
class Person(AbstractUser):
    company_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{last}, {first} ({id})".format(
            last=self.last_name, first=self.first_name, id=self.id
        )
```

If I leave the code like this, the authentication never takes place (and I end up in an infinite loop of redirections).

Now, if I update my model by adding:

```py
objects = models.Manager()
```

All of the sudden, the authentication takes place and it is (at least this part) is working fine.

I know that the custom authentication middleware is updating the database when the user logs in. However, I can't figure out why I should override `objects`

Comment: You refer to "the custom authentication middleware". Can we remove custom or do you actually have custom auth middleware?

Comment: @Melvyn this is really a custom Middleware. It's code would be far too long to post on SO

Comment: Then what is the loop exactly. My guess is that authentication and login succeeds, but the custom middleware doesn't set request.user and so authentication is redirected to login, which gets a logged in user, redirecting to homepage, etc. But without knowing what calls to the usermanager it makes it's going to be really hard to guess the root cause. But I'd first establish for certain why the loop is happening.

Comment: @Melvyn you're absolutely right that it's really hard without the middleware code. It's source code can be found at https://github.com/epfl-si/django-tequila. It actually does the login at https://github.com/epfl-si/django-tequila/blob/f93caf7a4a1190a006cddfab7ad0a6cc71348bcb/django_tequila/middleware.py#L107. However, what surprises me is why the objects should be overriden. Normally, it I don't do it, it should take the one from the parent (AbstractUser).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm surprised this middleware works, because it intercepts any page, including the authentication page and does authentication. If the setting `TEQUILA_CLEAN_URL` is set to a falsy value, then it will login the user and then let the login view run. If this is the standard login view and `redirect_authenticated_user` is set to the default of False, then the user will be logged out and logged in again.

My guess is (without putting it under the debugger) that this then fails in `auth.autenticate`:

```py
        try:
            user = UserModel._default_manager.get_by_natural_key(username)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            # Run the default password hasher once to reduce the timing
            # difference between an existing and a nonexistent user (#20760).
            UserModel().set_password(password)
```

Which means authentication fails and so your session isn't destroyed and you're actually logged in because the middleware already did it.

That `get_by_natural_key()` call is pretty much the only thing I can see in the auth and login flow that's different for the UserManager. But this theory hinges on the fact that `TEQUILA_CLEAN_URL` is set to False on your end. Otherwise, you'd have a redirect and not hit the login view.